# How to delete the blank sheets in the given workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub deleteemptysheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, c As Range
sh = Sheets(wb.Sheets)
    For Each c In wb.Sheets
        If IsEmpty(sh.UsedRange) Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next
Set sh = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set c = Nothing
End Sub
```

Question:I tried to delete the empty sheets, but I am not able to get the exact code. Can anyone help me in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not defining where `wb` comes from, and you're not using `sh` to iterate through the sheets.

I'm assuming you want to iterate through the sheets in the active workbook.  If so, you don't need `wb` or `c`.  Try this:

```
Sub deleteemptysheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If IsEmpty(sh.UsedRange) Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: i want to select the sheets from different workbooks by giving Inputbox.

Comment: Ok, then please update your question with the code that is calling deleteemptysheets()

Comment: Sub delete()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, c As Range
    wb = InputBox("work book name")
    sh = wb.Sheets
        For Each c In sh
            If IsEmpty(sh.UsedRange) Then
                sh.delete
            End If
        Next
End Sub